# Is there any Fourier transform Function in Appcelerator?

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, fft, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to take the FFT of an image inside an application for iOS and android. I was wondering if there is a built in function in appcelerator.
If not, What is the easiest way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator is a company. What you're trying to find is a function for Titanium. It actually is even easier than that. Titanium is build in JavaScript, and it supports nodejs packages and uses the commonjs approach.

So any commonjs module, or nodejs package (that doesn't rely on the nodejs core packages) are supported by Titanium.